# Data protection manager dji sdk

Tags: android, dji-sdk

Could we get more explanation of the data protection manager in the dji android mobile sdk.

From the sdk documentation - if the data protection manager is set to false then data is not sent to DJI servers unless you are in China.

What data is being sent when the data protection manager is set to true? The only data mentioned is sending the serial numbers of the drone and the rc. Could we have a comprehensive list of the data that is being sent and where it is being sent.

Also - how does the data protection manager different from the local data mode. It seems like the two capabilities have a certain amount of overlap.

Answer (score 1):

1. `authorizeAccessToDJIDeviceHardwareInfo(boolean hardwareInfoAuthorized)`: when `hardwareInfoAuthorized` is set to true, SDK will be allowed to send "serial numbers of the aircraft and the remote  controller" to a remote server. That is the only information SDK will send.
2. `DataProtectionManager` is to comply with GDPR. It allows user to selectively choose  the type of **privacy data** SDK can access. `LDM` is for user to restrict SDK's ability to access internet. This includes both **upload** and **download** ability, not just **upload** like `DataProtectionManager`. It applies to **any kind of data**, not exclusively to user **privacy data** like `DataProtectionManager`.